# str_wrap() and mutate() passed on to ggplot() inside a simple custom function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, stringr, dplyr

I created the following simple function to generate a bunch of stacked bar charts:

```
cntl <- function(.data, varname, colname, xlabname, maintitle){
  print (ggplot(.data) + 
           aes(x={{varname}}, fill=progcat) +
           geom_bar(position="fill") +
    scale_fill_manual(name="Control", values=c("#84c96d", "#cecece", "#ffcf5e", "#fa6b37")) +
    xlab(xlabname) + ylab("Proportion of Cohort") +
    labs (title=maintitle) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)))
  table(colname, df$control)
  chisq.test(table(colname, df$control))
  fisher.test(table(colname, df$control))
}
```

It works for the vast majority of the variables. However, I had to wrap one variable with `stringr` like this:

```
df$dx <- str_wrap(df$dx, width=10)
```

I also need to reorder the bars in this case. When I do the following, the graph does not output:

```
df %>%
  arrange (progcat) %>%
  mutate(dx=factor(dx,
                   levels=c("Smoldering/\nMGUS", "Stage I", "Stage II", "Stage III",
                            "Plasma\nCell\nLeukemia", "Unknown"))) %>%
  cntl (dx, df$dx, "Stage", "Long-Term Disease Control by Stage at Diagnosis")
```

But the same thing works when I take the `ggplot()` out of the function:

```
df %>%
  arrange (progcat) %>%
  mutate(dx=factor(dx,
                   levels=c("Smoldering/\nMGUS", "Stage I", "Stage II", "Stage III",
                            "Plasma\nCell\nLeukemia", "Unknown"))) %>%
  ggplot() +
         aes(x=dx, fill=progcat) +
         geom_bar(position="fill") +
         scale_fill_manual(name="Control", values=c("#84c96d", "#cecece", "#ffcf5e", "#fa6b37")) +
         xlab("Stage") + ylab("Proportion of Cohort") +
         labs (title="Long-Term Disease Control by Stage at Diagnosis") +
         theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
table(df$dx, df$control)
chisq.test(table(df$dx, df$control))
fisher.test(table(df$dx, df$control))
```

I think it has something to do with the text wrapping since the function works as written for all other unwrapped variables, even with a `mutate`. I'm a relative newbie to all this. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S. Here's some sample data prior to the wrap:

```
   progcat              dx
1        3       Stage III
2        3 Smoldering/MGUS
3        2         Unknown
4        4       Stage III
5        3       Stage III
6        4         Stage I
7        4       Stage III
8        1        Stage II
9        3         Unknown
10       3       Stage III
11       1         Unknown
12       3         Stage I
13       4         Stage I
14       1         Stage I
15       3       Stage III
16       2       Stage III
17       3 Smoldering/MGUS
18       4        Stage II
19       3 Smoldering/MGUS
20       3        Stage II
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example for testing

Comment: I've added sample records prior to the wrap in my original post.

Comment: FWIW, The function works if I don't wrap; it doesn't if I wrap.

Comment: Can you test the solution in my post.  it is giving the output similar to as outside the function now

Answer (score 0):

The call should be unquoted column name

```
df %>%
  arrange (progcat) %>%
   mutate(dx=factor(dx,
                    levels=c("Smoldering/\nMGUS", "Stage I", "Stage II", "Stage III",
                            "Plasma\nCell\nLeukemia", "Unknown"))) %>%
   cntl (dx, dx, "Stage", "Long-Term Disease Control by Stage at Diagnosis")
```

-function used

```
cntl <- function(.data, varname, colname, xlabname, maintitle){
  print (ggplot(.data) + 
           aes(x={{varname}}, fill=progcat) +
           geom_bar(position="fill") +
    scale_fill_manual(name="Control", values=c("#84c96d", "#cecece", "#ffcf5e", "#fa6b37")) +
    xlab(xlabname) + ylab("Proportion of Cohort") +
    labs (title=maintitle) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)))
}
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(progcat = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), dx = c("Stage III", "Smoldering/\nMGUS", 
"Unknown", "Stage III", "Stage III", "Stage I", "Stage III", 
"Stage II", "Unknown", "Stage III", "Unknown", "Stage I", "Stage I", 
"Stage I", "Stage III", "Stage III", "Smoldering/\nMGUS", "Stage II", 
"Smoldering/\nMGUS", "Stage II")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: My bad, the function actually has three more lines that actually call the colname argument. I've edited the function above to reflect the complete function.

Comment: @MWolcott but when you call the function, `cntl (dx, df$dx, "Stage", "Long-Term Disease Control by Stage at Diagnosis")` I believe the `df$dx` corresponds to `colname`?

Comment: Yes. `colname` is being used in the last three lines of the function (table and a couple of tests). It is not used in the plot. (I was too lazy to do it another way). What's puzzling to me is that when I try to `mutate()`, it works if either (1) I don't wrap the text in `df$dx` or (2) don't call it as a function. But do one of these two and it doesn't work.... And works just fine if I don't `mutate()`.

Comment: And works just fine if I don't `mutate()`. I need the categories to come in a certain order (Plasma Cell Leukemia needs to be after all the stages), so `mutate()` is necessary.